# Bind an event handler on a element who's inserted by the jQuery .html() function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, html-rendering

I render some new content with `.html()` after ajax call into my site.

```
$.getJSON(scriptURL, $("#domainForm").serialize(), function(data) {
  $("#checkedDomain").html(data['html']) 
});
```

Now. How can I bind an event handler to div tags in that replaced html without including the script again?
now the html the I render into my site looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"/>
<div id="tagWithHandlerOn"/>someButton</div>
```

I want to get rid of the `<script>` Tag because it's a redeclaration and if I load the same content into that tag again two scripts are going to be loaded. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

---

> **As of jQuery 1.7,** the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in preference to .live().

Answer (score 2):

$("#tagWithHandlerOn").live(event,handler) might just do the trick