# .html() added input box value does not take alert value

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind an event handler on a element who’s inserted by the jQuery .html() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003747/bind-an-event-handler-on-a-element-whos-inserted-by-the-jquery-html-function)

Below is a simple jquery script.  When the user hit #FAC a textbox appears, the value is entered.  When #cs is clicked the valued entered in #NC should appear as alert.  But it does not, any ideas to why?

```
$('#FAC').click(function() {
        $('#FAC').html('<input type="text" name="NC" id="NC"><input type="button" value="Ok" id="CS">');
    });

    $('#NC').click(function() {
        alert($('#NC').val());

    });
```

Comment: `#nc` should be capitalized. ;)

Comment: @VictorKilo sorry my mistake, the org was caps :)

Comment: Because the element with ID `NC` does not exist yet when you are trying to bind the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understand well your problem try this:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GXJDS/2/)

```
$('#FAC').bind("click",function() {
    $('#FAC').unbind("click");
    $(this).html('<input type="text" name="NC" id="NC"><input type="button" value="Ok" id="CS">');
})

$(document).on('click', '#CS', function() {
    alert($('#NC').val());

});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: @alessandro its not working.

Comment: This has the same problems as the OP's code... you have to use `.on` correctly.

Comment: @Jean: What do you mean with "nope"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry @FelixKlingit does not work.

Comment: @Jean: Yeah, that's what I'm saying... ;)

Comment: I have add another solution try that! it should work fine @Jean

Comment: You use `.live` again `:-/`.

Comment: ok update answer and jsfiddle now without live  @Jean

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroMinoccheri it works... the issue was with the bind/live/on

Answer (score 2):

The `<input id="NC" />` text box is added to the document only when the element with an ID of `FAC` has been clicked, so using `$('#NC')` immediately won't find any elements to attach your click handler to.

There are two options, either add the click handler once it is in the document:

```
$('#FAC').click(function() {
    $('#FAC').html('<input type="text" name="NC" id="NC"><input type="button" value="Ok" id="CS">');
    $('#NC').click(function() { /* alert here */ });
});
```

or add a delegate handler on an element that filters clicks by the `NC` id:

```
$('#FAC').click(function() {
    $('#FAC').html('<input type="text" name="NC" id="NC"><input type="button" value="Ok" id="CS">');
});
$(document).on('click', '#NC', function() { /* alert here */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#FAC').click(function() {
   $('#FAC').html('<input type="text" name="NC" id="NC"><input type="button" value="Ok" id="CS">');
   $('#FAC').unbind('click'); // to stop events bubbling up to the parent
});

$('#CS').on('click',function() {
    alert($('#NC').val());
});
```

Note that you want to show the alert value when `#CS` is clicked, but have been trying it on `#NC` click event.

Also, since the `#NC` and `#CS` were created on the fly, you can't use a direct `.click()` method. Instead, you need a `.on()` method